# oracle sql find time difference (both time in string)

Tags: sql, oracle, time, datetime-format, date-arithmetic

In my db i have 2 columns START_TIME, END_TIME, both in VARCHAR2(8), i need to find the duration by using END_TIME- START_TIME.

```
START_TIME | END_TIME | DURATION

 21:30:03    21:34:11   00:04:08
```

I want to do something like the following, how can i do that?

```
SELECT TO_DATE(END_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS END, 
       TO_DATE(START_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS START, 
       (END-START) AS duration FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a **flawed design**.

- You should never store a **datetime** value as **string**.
- **DATE** always has both date and time elements, so no need to store the time element separately.

Anyway, as a workaround, you need to first convert the string into date and then find the duration in **seconds**, add the seconds to `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`, then the rest is simple **date formatting**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT '21:30:03' START_TIME, '21:34:11' END_TIME FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT start_time,
  5    end_time,
  6    TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE) + (to_date(end_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') -
  7                                to_date(start_time, 'HH24:MI:SS')
  8                               ) , 'hh24:mi:ss' ) duration
  9  FROM sample_data;

START_TI END_TIME DURATION
-------- -------- --------
21:30:03 21:34:11 00:04:08

SQL>
```